# Character.isLetterOrDigit(char) returns different value in java 6 and 7

Tags: java

The following code snippet returns 46059 on Java 6 and 48757 on Java 7. Any ideas what might have changed?

```
int i = 0;
for(char c = Character.MIN_VALUE; c < Character.MAX_VALUE; c++){
    if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)){
        i++;
    }
}
System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: (Most likely more character sets were added to 7.)

Comment: print out the character together with the outcome of `isLetterOrDigit` and compare the outputs.  Either they changed the definition of some, or they support more characters.

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx -- Printing out 65K "outcomes" would be a bit of a task.

Comment: @PP - The point is that there's no practical way to do an "iterative" search.  But with a "binary search" you do each in halves, then quarters, then eighths, etc, until you narrow in on the difference.  It's tedious but doable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suspect [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/enhancements.7.html) holds the answer:

> **New Scripts and Characters from Unicode 6.0.0**
>   Early versions of the Java SE 7 release added support for Unicode 5.1.0. The final version of the Java SE 7 release supports Unicode 6.0.0. Unicode 6.0.0 is a major version of the Unicode Standard and adds support for over 2000 additional characters, as well as support for properties and data files.

Comment: Also javadoc for `Character` show different level of unicode support for [6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) and [7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)